# How to update code changes automatically in google appscripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I am using a tracker for my team to track their progress. At the beginning, I make duplicates of a mastersheet which has a code already in it. But If i want anything to be changed in the code, I will have to manually go to all sheets and make the changes. Is there a work around where I can change the code in all sheet if I change the code in my mastersheet?

Comment: No that's not possible.

Comment: I believe you can make changes in other projects code and I think you can actually create code but I’ve never done it utilizing the Google app script API the rest API. I have use the API to read code in my current project and to get function names in certain pages of my project but that’s all I’ve done with that API

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into libraries? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Using these concepts, you could publish a library and give all of those people edit access, then in the original spreadsheet access the library through development mode (or head deployment for the new IDE), and then they can get real-time updates to the code implemented in their script. This is best if it's ok to give edit access to the library to everyone; if it's view access only it's more complicated but still possible. Can provide an edit if you need to give view access.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can make changes to Apps Script code in other files using the [`projects.updateContent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent) method of the Apps Script API.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation:

> [This method] Updates the content of the specified script project. This content is stored as the HEAD version, and is used when the script is executed as a trigger, in the script editor, in add-on preview mode, or as a web app or Apps Script API in development mode. This clears all the existing files in the project.

In order to update code in other projects you must provide the enire script of all files, and not just the newly updated functions.

The request needs to be to:

```
PUT https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{scriptId}/content
```

and the request body takes the form:

```js
{
  "files": [
    {
      "name": string,
      "type": enum (FileType),
      "source": string,
      "lastModifyUser": {
        "domain": string,
        "email": string,
        "name": string,
        "photoUrl": string
      },
      "createTime": string,
      "updateTime": string,
      "functionSet": {
        "values": [
          {
            "name": string
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Remember that you must inclide the `appsscript.json` manifest file when using this endpoint.

#### References:

- [Method: projects.updateContent | Apps Script API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)

Comment: This is an option but requires the owner of the script to be an editor on all other files; the above solution requires the owner to only allow other users to edit their own files.