# How do I make one code file apply to multiple spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, for context, I am doing this for Dungeons and Dragons. I made a character sheet template for my players and I have been regularly updating it. I recently discovered scripts and I've been integrating them into my players sheets.

The problem is that every time I edit or update the code, I have to copy and paste to 6 other
files (It uses onEdit).

Is there a way to make it so that I have a single file that applies to all of them?

Comment: You can put your code in a library and then add it as a resource to the spreadsheet.  That way you edit your library and any updates are automatically seen be all the users.  See this article https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Comment: It's possible to write a script using apps script api that will modify all of you spreadsheets at the same and thus avoid using libraries which have been known to create some difficulties difficulties.  I know it possible because I do it.

Comment: @Cooper do you have link to more information on that technique?

Comment: Yeah if you go to the google apps script documentation and click on "Use the Rest API" at the top.  It's in there and you can and you can use `"headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }` for authorization.  I find using the urls easier to figure rather than using Google Apps Script Directly ...which I don't think that have for this.

Comment: I actually have use the code to assemble projects and the only thing I have to go in and tweak is the manifest which I still haven't really mastered.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65548827/1595451